# Intuitive explanation behind conditional mean independence?

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, linear

From what I understand from $E(U|X) = 0$

is that: for every slice of X (i.e. if we fix X, we can get a (normal) distribution of Y values that tend (as the definition of normal distribution) to cluster around the mean)

I see this in my head as: for a particular X value (e.g. education = 5 years),we observe many individuals with different incomes that form a distribution. We allow the randomness to "cancel" each other out to give a mean tendency.

And linear regression is just putting a line through all the means for all X

However, I am now learning about time series, and I am seeing a different form of this assumption:
$E(X_i| U_i) = 0$, and it is explained as : for a particular person's value of Y (e.g. income), it is mean independent of his X value ( education level)

I find this hard to grasp: how do we get a distribution of values for only one particular individual? How do we allow the same process of finding a mean tendency from a (normal or not) distribution?

Maybe I am not understanding the whole assumption in the correct way either. Would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Could you please give some context as well, like a reference to where you have faced this?